# How do I detect sqlite file replacement while app is running?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a java application that uses an sqlite db.

About once a month, we "sync changes" by pulling down the most up to date version of the sqlite db and replace the existing one.

Is there any way for sqlite to automatically detect the file change?

**Potentially Helpful Context**

I'm using the sqlite xerial jdbc driver. We'll only do reads from the db.

```
SQLiteConfig sqliteConfig = new SQLiteConfig();
sqliteConfig.setReadOnly(true);
sqliteConfig.setJournalMode(SQLiteConfig.JournalMode.OFF);
sqliteConfig.setOpenMode(SQLiteOpenMode.NOMUTEX);
sqliteConfig.setSharedCache(true); 
SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource(sqliteConfig);
dataSource.setUrl(connectionString);
```

Comment: Perhaps take advantage of the Java [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) API. You may find [this](https://dzone.com/articles/listening-to-fileevents-with-java-nio) of interest as well.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing